# WordPress Adds Unwanted Blank Lines to Files

Tags: php, wordpress, file, auto-update, blank-line

When I open my WordPress files (config.php or PHP theme files), suddenly I have multiple blank lines added inside my code.

**Example before:**
[image]

**Example after:**
[image]

I don't know why this happened.

It is because of Wordpress automatic updates?

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Do you transfer the file? Seems to be a platform/end-of-line conversion problem.

Comment: there is nothing related to updates. what editor do you use for open the files?

Comment: I have noticed this happened sometimes after editing files in the WordPress dashboard and then opening them later with a file editor. I am interested in why this might happen as well, but I feel like it may be an issue with the browser or editor that is being used.

Comment: I use Dreamweaver as editor and PHP storm. But it can't be due to Editor, because all files (even one I didn't touch) in any editor have blank lines sudently...

Comment: Maybe it's related to GoDaddy File Managers ? When I copy or compress/extract entire site to another folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem! 
Effectively, it's related to **Dreamweaver** editor...

I changed the option inside **Preferences->Code format->Line Break Type** :

CR LF (Windows) to **LF (Unix)**

Now my files open correctly if it was edited previously in PHP Storm and re-open with Dreamweaver after.

Thank you for your hypotheses, that help me find the problem!